# Insert value into field before and after specific string

Tags: database, updating

I need help with update function.

I have database table with three fields. One of them is code field with html div and script. 
Example:
`<div id='id1'></div><script type="text/javascript">/* Banner */</script>`
My problem is, how am i supposed to insert some condition inside script tags and to end it before closing script tag? How should i write `db_update` to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be parsing the field with a regex function that matches the content between the script tags. Then you can rebuild your string and update the row.

http://regexr.com/3du5i for an example

Comment: That isn't exactly what i'm searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some time, i have found a solution with `drupal_substr`. First cut off the starting part and ending part and after that just take out the middle part and wrap it in a new variable with conditions between the parts.

Comment: It is not a good approach, you should use DOMDocument or other similar library to understand the HTML structure to revise the content.